# startx resolution

Tags: xorg

Focal Fosa 20.04, I used I3 but after the last update (I am not sure yet) when I startx the I3 is too small. I do not know where to start troubleshooting. Not sure if is a font or resolution issue.
I removed I3 config and reconfigure but still very small.

I do not have many X conf files. Thanks!

Comment: Could you share a screenshot? This would let people familiar with i3 identify whether it's font or resolution.